# Design entities with relationship ManyToOne

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities **User** and **Agency** and each user can create his own agency. An agency can has many landlines, many mobile phones, many faxes, many emails ...

The right way for design is to make an entity for each one ?

For example entity **Landline**, entity **MobilePhone**, entity **Fax** , entity **Email**... then make a ManyToOne relationship with entity or **Agency** or there is another good way ?

Comment: The user to agency relationship should just be `hasAgency` and the rest of your requisites should just be `hasMany`

Comment: I would just create two entities for the contact information: one for telephone numbers (two fields: telephone number + type: landline/mobile/fax), one for email. Then you can indeed create a many to one relationship between the Agency and those contact entities.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off creating 2 entities User and ContactInfo.  User has a one to many relationship with ContactInfo and ContactInfo has a many to one relationship with User.  Contact info will have the fields typeId and info where typeId has mapped constants and info is just whatever the value.

For example, your contactInfo table might look like:

```
1 = landline
2 = mobile
3 = fax
4 = email

typeId | userId  |  info
*****************************
1      |   1     |  (111) 111-1111
4      |   1     |  bobdole@bobdole.com
2      |   2     |  (222) 222-2222
```

this way if you need to add a new form of contact information you can just add support for a new typeId and you'll be good to go.  Adding a complete new entity for every form of contact is a very difficult way of managing data.